# how to determine if a sprite is in a layer

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cclayer

Sorry if this sounds quite trivial. I am just not getting it. How can one determine if a particular sprite is already in a layer? Basically, I need to check this before determining whether to add it to the layer or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if ( [ myNode.children indexOfObject:sprite ] == NSNotFound ) {

     // you can add the code here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's so many ways:

1) try to get child

```
if (![layer getChild:sprite]) {
   // Your code
}
```

2) try to get child by tag

```
if (![layer getChildByTag:spriteTag]) {
   // Your code
}
```

3) Check if sprite is on children array (like @oopology answer)

```
if ([layer.children indexOfObject:sprite] == NSNotFound) {
   // Your code
}
```